# Where does this sailor beside Bender come from?

Tags: character-identification, art, reference

In school we were interpreting a painting from Slovak artist Erik Šille called Wave ([Vlna](http://eriksille.com/works/vlna)). He used a lot of pop-culture references, but we didn't recognize this little sailor. Is he from a cartoon or a commercial?

[image: A close-up of the sailor boy] [image: The complete painting]

Comment: While I see Bender, I'm not sure what makes you think this particular character is SF&F related...

Comment: @ZeissIkon The painting also has Pikachu and some other SFF characters in it so it's possible the character is SFF-nal too.

Comment: I have a feeling it _might_ be his son. I've reached out to the artist though for confirmation.

Comment: Ditto. Sent him an email.

Comment: looks like a Dutch Boy-esque character

Comment: @ZeissIkon I don´t have any clue, but cause most of characters are from sff related work, Ive tried it here... maybe someone will know it from some old cartoon...

Comment: Possibly the [Cracker Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracker_Jack) boy? The uniform is different (though it still has a nautical theme), but the hair and age match.